# theForm.__EVENTVALIDATION

Tags: asp.net, forms

```
theForm.__EVENTVALIDATION.value
```

I got this: What does it mean? And how to encode it?

```
"jSp677t39HyhECAmULmdU/ya3EVJgkk8dokDchVgxoH1wOfuygSJwIY8Nxw+5+Le3r3JZ49UYhuxPKvdaGyMv1JyCPLXT0tWnpJryLqScc8a5QCNfiRu5ufIEjsqOCKdGMFTd33wdI3QJM2+ElSwe9V7K/8HiEXBYwvR/bXh8Xvrtkh8XspsxF0ADYMnzWTlUvk0ODQRofXwlYcAfUZ4wuzjG+X1b2G4mjON1zYPO6c4TGlofRap39VyxZ6RX2pBYLtcwahOUo6nX4zD7ICJeSu4mkIoo/W5eW9qWRClbEWgA6NZs/dyTlT/TB9q7xtx/ghBfogHOddtsOWQxSQzyFcz0xYLOKdtqbf6uzpwgBz3vBsbevNoXwG0KIjCz+fxW8yaEzpcywZBAxJV4vzXRLFu39Mti5PHXpGJ0C7iEQ7Vc2Ema9sNNF1wpCzdc0j50+tXhw=="
```

Answer (score 0):

The event validation feature is designed to minimize the risk of an attacker tampering with values that are posted back to the server.  A brief description of the feature can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx.  Lots of blog posts on this feature if you search http://www.bing.com/search?q=event+validation.

As for the field value, it is an opaque string.  It is not meant to be decipherable by the application.